# User agent string of Opera Mini on iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-agent, opera-mini

So hell froze over and Apple accepted Opera Mini into the app store. Does anyone know what the user agent string will be?

[The documentation](http://my.opera.com/community/openweb/idopera/) says that Opera's template is like this:

> Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/$CLIENT_VERSION/$SERVER_VERSION; U; $LANGUAGE) Presto/$PRESTO_VERSION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Opera Mini UA string was [updated to include "iPhone"](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221034354/http://my.opera.com/haavard/blog/2010/04/16/iphone-user-agent) one day after release, FYI.

```
Opera/9.80 (iPhone; Opera Mini/5.0.0176/764; U; en) Presto/2.4.15
```

@BubbleBum: Sounds like more of a problem with your mobile provider, than Opera Mini or any other browser they stupidly block. Did you ping them and ask them to unblock Opera Mini?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/5.0.0176/1150; U; en) Presto/2.4.15</strike>

EDITED: Old string, didn't make it into production, as per accepted answer.

Comment: so no mention of iPhone in there?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Opera Mini for iPhone’s User-Agent string: <strike>`Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/5.0.0176/742; U; en) Presto/2.4.155`</strike>

EDITED: That string, didn't make it into production, as per accepted answer, despite the below article being correct at the time.

[Opera iPhone app review](http://www.appsafari.com/utilities/11362/opera-mini-browser-for-iphone/)